# Customizing action bar using ActionBarSherlok

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm trying to customize the my action bar. I'm using [ActionBarSherlok](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

I have created this theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="actionBarSize">80dip</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dip</item>
</style>
```

I've already customized the height of the tab.

Now I want modify the text size inside each tab and the size of the Activity title.
How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this still helps... please, let me know :)

```
<style name="Theme.MyActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan, it works. But where I can find all the Theme of Sherlok? for example how did you know about TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title Theme? Or how did you know about "titleTextStyle" ? Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: you're welcome @Joseph82. Easiest way for me is always check the android developers link for customizing the actionbar [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) Then, usually all the attributes follow the style Theme.Sherlock. +style name for native actionbar, so I try on. In case the attribute does not work, I do a search for it.